# Свой шифр (замена символов) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, шифрование

Сегодня я начал писать простой шифр и столкнулся с проблемой – замена происходит в некоторых частях.

Заменял я вот это:

```
hello world
```

Ожидание:

```
abiik nkvif
```

А получил:

```
aeiio worid
```

Собственно вот код (я ещё не доделал):

```
print('1 - Закодирование файла')
oper = input('Выберете операцию: ')

if str(oper) == str(1):
    file = input('Название файла: ')
    of = open(file,'r')
    ce = of.read()
    a = ce
    b = a.replace('q','m')
    c = b.replace('w','n')
    d = c.replace('e','b')
    e = d.replace('r','v')
    f = e.replace('t','c')
    g = f.replace('y','x')
    h = g.replace('u','z')
    i = h.replace('i','l')
    j = i.replace('o','k')
    k = j.replace('p','j')
    l = k.replace('a','h')
    m = l.replace('s','g')
    n = m.replace('d','f')
    o = n.replace('f','d')
    p = o.replace('g','s')
    q = p.replace('h','a')
    r = q.replace('j','p')
    s = r.replace('k','o')
    t = s.replace('l','i')
    u = t.replace('z','u')
    v = u.replace('x','y')
    w = v.replace('c','t')
    x = w.replace('v','r')
    y = x.replace('b','e')
    z = y.replace('n','w')
    z2 = a.replace('m','q')
    of.close
    of = open(file,'w')
    of.write(z2)
```

Пытался заменить 1 букву на разные (уже сделано в коде) – не помогло. Результат тот же.

Comment: вот кстати bash: `echo "hello world" | tr 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm' 'mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq'`

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим букву w. Сначала w заменится на n `c = b.replace('w','n')`. А потом n, на которое изменилось w, заменится на w `z = y.replace('n','w')`. Поэтому кажется, что не изменилась буква, хотя она изменялась дважды (w->n->w). Нужно сделать посимвольную проверку строки.

```py
f_kripto=open('kripto.txt', 'w')
for i in range(int(len(ce))):
    \\здесь идЁт замена i-ого символа согласно твоей таблице
    if ce[i]=='q':
        f_kripto.write('m')
    \\и так далее, через elif
f_kripto.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

В Python уже есть встроенная функция для этого.

### [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

```py
In [1]: s1 = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'

In [2]: s2 = 'mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq'

In [3]: translation = str.maketrans(s1, s2)

In [4]: "Super string".translate(translation)
Out[4]: 'Szjbv gcvlws'

In [5]: "hello world".translate(translation)
Out[5]: 'abiik nkvif'
```

Comment: bash:`echo "hello world" | tr 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm' 'mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq'`

Answer (score 1):

Вместо вашей долгой последовательности просто примените **словарь** — его можете создать например так:

```
from_letter = 'qwerty...'
to_letter   = 'mnbvcx...'

change_to = dict(zip(from_letter, to_letter))
```

Затем примените его для шифрования:

```
encoded = ''

for letter in ce:
    encoded += change_to[letter]
```

---

Вся ваша программа может затем выглядеть так:

```
from_letter = 'qwerty...'
to_letter   = 'mnbvcx...'
change_to = dict(zip(from_letter, to_letter))
change_to['\n'] = ['\n']

print('1 - Закодирование файла')
oper = input('Выберете операцию: ')

if oper == '1':                    
    filename = input('Название файла: ')
    with open(filename) as of:
        ce = of.read()
    encoded = ''
    for letter in ce:
        encoded += change_to[letter]
    with open(filename, 'w') as of:
        of.write(encoded)
```

Comment: bash:`echo "hello world" | tr 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm' 'mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq'`